# Create hmacHash with stream result differs for requests with formatted json

Tags: c#, utf-8, streamreader, memorystream, hmacsha256

I want to regenerate a token to verify the request using hmacHash
The resource documentation is in javascript and I have to implement it in C#.
here what I found in their documentation on generating the token.

```js
routes.post("/webhook", (request) => {
  const body          = request.rawBody;
  const signatureTime = "2022-05-17T09:47:51.935Z";
  const signingKey = "localyStoredKey";

  const hmac = createHmac("sha256", signingKey);
  hmac.update(`${signatureTime}${body}`);

  const token = hmac.digest("hex");
}
```

here is what I have done in C#

```cs
public async Task<string> GetWebhookAuthenticationTokenAsync(Stream requestBody) // requestBody is from HttpContext.Request.Body
{
    var signingKey = "localyStoredKey"; // should be from db
    var signatureTime = "2022-05-17T09:47:51.935Z"; // a timestamp

    var reader = new StreamReader(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8);
    var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    var byteArray1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{signatureTime}");
    var byteArray2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);

    var concatenatedByteArray = byteArray1.Concat(byteArray2).ToArray();
    var stringInMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(concatenatedByteArray);
    
    using var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingKey));
    var hashBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(stringInMemoryStream);

    var token = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
    return token;
}
```

This works fine when I send the request body(`json`) without newline characters(`\n`).
when I send the formatted json body with the request, the token is different from javascript generated token. What am I missing?
simply if json is `{"pro": "duct"}` the tokens are matched but when json `{\n    "pro": "duct"\n}` its different.

PS: I found the issue is due to Carriage Return `\r` in json body. Any help to handle this independently from the platform?

Comment: Do you really need to convert a request body to a string before hash computation? Can you pass a raw bytes into the `ComputeHash`? I suspect the problem is due to sting manipulation like difference in newline sequence (`\r\n` or `\n` on different platforms) or something similar.

Comment: @serg not really, so I removed the code of converting to body and used `MemomoryStream` `await requestBody.CopyToAsync(ms);` and converted it to array. no luck

Comment: Yes, @serg I tried removing '\r' from the body and now it's matched. might need to handle Carriage Return properly

Comment: maybe try to minify the JSON object beforehand.